# hydrate() function not called php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i am trying to create a event to call it on javascript in component blade , but i think hydrate method not called when the page is refreshed. i try to log a some text when the page refresh in hydrate function, but still not working , nothing appear , plus i try use emit function in hydrate but still not working , any help?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Students;

use App\Models\Student;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Models\Skill;
use App\Models\StudentsSkills;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;



class StudentIndex extends Component
{
    public $students;
    public $addStudent = false;
    public $updateStudent = false;
    public $name;
    public $mail;
    public $phone;
    public $studentId;
    public $selectedSkill;
    public $skillsField = [];
    public $allSkills;
    public $type;
    protected $listeners = ['deleteStudent' => 'deleteStudent'];
    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'mail' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'selectedSkill.*.id' => 'required'
    ];


    public function mount($studentId = "")
    {
        $this->allSkills = Skill::select('id', 'name')->get();
        $this->students = Student::select('id', 'name', 'mail', 'phone')->get();
        if (isset($this->studentId)) {
            $student = Student::with('studentSkills')->find($this->studentId);
        }

        // $this->emitTo('student', 'showStudents', $this->students);
    }
    public function hydrate()
    {
        Log::info('Hydrate method called.');
        $this->students = Student::select('id', 'name', 'mail', 'phone')->get();
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('showStudents', ['students' => $this->students]);
    }


    public function addSkillField()
    {
        $this->selectedSkill[] = ['id' => ''];
        $this->skillsField[] = ['id' => ''];
    }

    public function removeSkillField($index)
    {
        unset($this->selectedSkill[$index]);
        $this->selectedSkill = array_values($this->selectedSkill);
        unset($this->skillsField[$index]);
        $this->skillsField = array_values($this->skillsField);
    }

    public function addStudent()
    {
        $this->addStudent = true;
        $this->updateStudent = false;
    }

    public function cancelStudent()
    {
        $this->addStudent = false;
        $this->updateStudent = false;
        return Redirect::to('/student');
    }

    public function storeStudent()
    {

        try {
            $this->validate();
            $student = Student::create([
                'name' => $this->name,
                'mail' => $this->mail,
                'phone' => $this->phone
            ]);
            $student_id = $student->id;

            $selectedSkillIds = array_column($this->selectedSkill, 'id');
            $uniqueSkillIds = array_unique($selectedSkillIds);
            $this->selectedSkill = array_map(function ($id) {
                return ['id' => $id];
            }, $uniqueSkillIds);
            // dd($this->selectedSkill);
            foreach ($this->selectedSkill as $skill) {

                $studentsSkills = new StudentsSkills();

                $studentsSkills->student_id = $student_id;
                $studentsSkills->skill_id = $skill["id"];
                $studentsSkills->save();
            }

            session()->flash('success', 'Student added Successfully!!');
            $this->addStudent = false;
            return Redirect::to('/student');
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Error: ' . $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function editStudent($studentId)
    {

        $student = Student::with('studentSkills')->findOrFail($studentId);

        try {
            if (!$student) {
                session()->flash('error', 'Student not found');
            } else {

                $this->name = $student->name;
                $this->studentId = $student->id;
                $this->mail = $student->mail;
                $this->phone = $student->phone;
                $this->selectedSkill = [];
                foreach ($student->studentSkills as $skill) {
                    $this->selectedSkill[] = ['id' => $skill->skill_id];
                }
                $this->updateStudent = true;
                $this->addStudent = false;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Something goes wrong!!');
        }
    }

    public function updateStudent()
    {
        try {

            $student = Student::with('studentSkills')->find($this->studentId);

            $oldSkills = $student->studentSkills->pluck('skill_id')->toArray();
            $newSkills = array_column($this->selectedSkill, 'id');
            $addedSkills = array_diff($newSkills, $oldSkills);

            $removedSkills = array_diff($oldSkills, $newSkills);
            //dd($addedSkills,$removedSkills);


            foreach ($addedSkills as $skill) {
                // dd($skill);
                //dd($skill);
                $studentsSkills = new StudentsSkills();
                $studentsSkills->skill_id = $skill;
                $studentsSkills->student_id = $this->studentId;
                $studentsSkills->save();
            }

            foreach ($removedSkills as $skill) {
                StudentsSkills::where([
                    'skill_id' => $skill,
                    'student_id' => $this->studentId
                ])->delete();
            }

            session()->flash('success', 'Student information Updated Successfully!!');
            $this->updateStudent = false;
            return Redirect::to('/student');
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            // DB::rollback();
            session()->flash('error', 'Error: ' . $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function deleteStudent($studentId)
    {
        try {
            $student = Student::with("studentSkills")->find($studentId);
            if ($student) {
                $student->delete();
                session()->flash('success', "Student deleted Successfully!!");
            } else {
                session()->flash('error', 'Student not found');
            }
            return Redirect::to('/student');
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Error: ' . $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function confirmDelete($studentId)
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('confirmDelete', ['studentId' => $studentId, 'type' => 'student']);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('showStudents', ['students' => $this->students]);
        return view('livewire.students.student-index');
    }

    // public function hydrate()
    // {
    //     Log::info('Hydrate method called.');
    //     $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('showStudents', ['students' => $this->students]);
    // }
}
```

Comment: Does this [article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-hydrate-not-working) fixes the issue?

Comment: 2x hydrate() one is commented. just put the necessary.